# How to set the icon into Treeview?

Tags: delphi, treeview, icons

I'm setting image indexes like this:

```
with TN do
begin
ImageIndex := 1;
SelectedIndex := 1;
end;
```

Problem:

I use the same code for three icons in various places through my main unit (when I'm adding nodes). I set the icon with the same approach each time.

The first icon (which happens to be on a parent node), displays correctly.
The second icon (which is the first child node) displays incorrectly until a third (second child) node is added, or until I click on the node with the incorrect image.

Suggestions?

Comment: When it displays incorrectly, what appears instead? Are you sure the parent node's correct display is just coincidence? Do other parent nodes appear correctly? What if your incorrect nodes are parents instead of children? There are many things you can test to narrow the scope of the problem so that your title can be something more descriptive than "weirdness."

Comment: First two things that pop into mind is you may have trouble with 'with' if you've been nesting them (or forgotten an 'end;'), and that SelectIndex is only shown when the item has focus (dotted box around it, shown in 'selected' color)

Comment: Stijn, please don't confuse selection with focus. They're two independent things.

Comment: The Second node, which is a child of the first node, displays the parent node's icon, until however, I click on the child node.

Comment: I assume the parent's image index is zero. Does the second node always display the *parent's* image, or does it simply display whatever image is at index zero? There are many variables in play; find out which ones are important and which are just coincidental.

Comment: Yeah that's weird. Parent node always have an imageindex of 0 (at least that's the goal). I tried changing it to 2, and now the parent node is doing the same thing (index 0 until clicked). What's it all mean?

Comment: This is still unsolved for me. There are no missing ';' and I am setting the correct index on both ImageIndex and SelectedIndex.